# Phonegap v3.3 - Android Video Plugin

Tags: cordova

I'm having trouble implementing https://github.com/raulduran/VideoPlayer.

I keep getting the following error:

THREAD WARNING: exec() call to VideoPlayer.playVideo blocked the main thread for 32ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this? I'm not sure if its my implimentation, or if the plugin just does not work in v3.3 yet.

Comment: Does the plugin actually not work? This warning pops up in a lot of plugins and core plugins, but so far I've never seen it actually cause an app to crash.

Answer (score 1):

I just got it all working and I'm not 100% sure why its working now, but I think the plugins are not done initializing even after app.initialize() says its ready. Here is a brief description of how I got it to work after all is said and done.

What I did was first include all my javascript files in this order (you may not need all of these):

Then I ran "app.initalize();", then run a setTimeout for 750ms, inside the timeout, I ran my jQuery that binds the $("div.play_video").click method to running the cordova.plugins.videoPlayer.play("file:///android_asset/www/videos/example_video.mp4"); method.

For some reason, even if I put the binding code into the app.initalize() its plugins were still not ready for me to bind them like that. setTimeout for just a few milliseconds fixed it all.